# setTimeout() countdown not working Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, settimeout

Idk why but if i skip or stop a song and the queue becomes empty , the countdown of timeout2 of bot disconnecting doesn't go on. I tested it  without clearTimeout() and the countdown worked , so maybe i should declare cleartimeout somewhere else or add something besides it .. Help me out i can't figure it out

```
function play(guild, song) {

  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

  if (!song) {
   

   var timeout = setTimeout(function() {const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play('./911.mp3');}, 1500);
   var timeout2 = setTimeout(function() {serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();}, 10000);
   clearTimeout(timeout2);

  queue.delete(guild.id); 
  return ;

} 

     options = {
    quality: 'highestaudio'
  };

  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection

    .play(ytdl(song.url, { highWaterMark: 1 << 25 }))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  serverQueue.textChannel.send(":musical_note: Started Playing: " + `**${song.title}**`);



}
```

Comment: Why do you have clearTimeout at all?

Comment: @James because if i play a song during the countdown of 10 seconds , the bot won't disconnect anymore .

Comment: I would think you want to abort the disconnect if they successfully play a song, not if they try to play a (!song).  Maybe you need an else in that if which does the clearTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if (!song) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play('./911.mp3');
            setTimeout(function () {
                serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
                queue.delete(guild.id);
            }, 8500);
        }, 1500);
    }
    else {
        options = {
            quality: 'highestaudio'
        };
        const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
            .play(ytdl(song.url, { highWaterMark: 1 << 25 }))
            .on("finish", () => {
                serverQueue.songs.shift();
                play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
            })
            .on("error", error => console.error(error));
        dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
        serverQueue.textChannel.send(":musical_note: Started Playing: " + `**${song.title}**`);
    }
}
```

This would probably suit your purpose

Comment: doesn't quite work, after stopping the queue , and then starting one again in that 10 seconds countdown ,  instead of pushing the next song to play it , it puts the song that is said in those 10 seconds in queue ( that means no song is played  ) ... here is the full code https://textuploader.com/1epzm